# Warning as Error 2008 is not a valid warning number

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, .net-2.0

I converted one of the .net 2.0 (VS2005) solution to work with VS2010 (didn't change the framework). Now when I try to build I keep getting this error message:

> 'Warning as Error 2008 is not a valid warning number'.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: I get the same warning after transfering a solution from `Visual C# Express 2010` on Windows 7 Pro 64bit to `Visual C# Express 2010` on Windows 7 Pro 32bit. Same IDE, same OS, just 64bit/32bit difference...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are there any `@pragma warning`s in the project? Do you get a line number with your error?

**EDIT:**

Try unchecking `treat warnings as errors` in your project config. That should allow you to compile.

Comment: did quick search on keyword @pragma on entire solution and i didn't find anything. I see the error message but the line column is empty.

Comment: check my edit, looks like this is a bug in VS. Look here for more info: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/694800/error-cs1691-warning-as-error-2008-is-not-a-valid-warning-number

Comment: Greg, you are having that problem after you installed VS2011. I never installed VS2011 in my comp.

Comment: Here's another SO answer to that question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2520873/1355166

Comment: I have the same error after downloading and installing VS 2010 express and the now-unsupported XNA 4.0 framework.  The install was fresh on a brand-new computer with nothing on it (just got it).  I have the same error, so it's not something caused by messing stuff up yourself.