# How can I fix the error : "Unreachable Code Detected"

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
private string GetAnswer()
{
   ....
}

private int CountLeapYears(DateTime startDate)
{
    return count;
    String answer = GetAnswer();
    Response.Write(lblAntwoord); 
}
```

Why do I get the error :

> Unreachable code detected

The error is shown on the following line `String answer = GetAnswer();`

Answer (score 37):

It's just because your code comes after the return statement.

> The return statement **terminates execution of the method** in which it
> appears and returns control to the calling method. It can also return
> an optional value. If the method is a void type, the return statement
> can be omitted.
>
> If the return statement is inside a try block, the finally block, if one exists, will be executed before control returns to the calling method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1h3swy84%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

solution (obvious) :

move the unreachable code before the return statement.

Answer (score 9):

Unreachable code is a compiler *warning*, not error. You have three options:

- Remove the unreachable code.
- [Stop treating warnings as errors in the project properties.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520853/warning-as-error-how-to-rid-these)
- Move the return statement to below what is currently unreachable.

It is unreachable because the flow of the method exits at the `return` statement, and thus will never execute the code below. The compiler can determine this and so can report it. Like I said, these are actually compiler *warnings* and won't stop a successful build unless you have configured the project to treat warnings as errors.

Answer (score 2):

The statement:

```
return count;
```

Exits the function. Therefore,

```
answer = GetAnswer(); 
Response.Write(lblAntwoord);
```

cannot be reached.

Answer (score 0):

> The **return** statement terminates the execution of a function and returns control to the calling function. Execution resumes in the calling function at the point immediately following the call
>
> If **no return** statement appears in a function definition, control automatically returns to the calling function after the last statement of the called function is executed

In Your Code :

```
private int CountLeapYears(DateTime startDate)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int year = startDate.Year; year <= DateTime.Now.Year; year++)
    {
        if (DateTime.IsLeapYear(year))
        {
            DateTime february29 = new DateTime(year, 2, 29);
            if (february29 >= startDate && february29 <= DateTime.Now.Date)
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;//The Execution will be terminated here,the next lines will become unreachable 
    **String** answer = GetAnswer();
    Response.Write(lblAntwoord); 
}
}
```

MSDN LINK :

> C : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sta56yeb.aspx
>
> c# : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1h3swy84.aspx