# Red build on invalid html razor with MvcBuildViews

Tags: c#, razor, msbuild

Is it possible to get a red build whenever the html in a razor template is invalid? I thought it already worked that way... But I guess not.

```
<div>
  @Html.DisplayTextFor(model => model.FooterText) // this will be a build error 
</div>

<div class="banana> // this isn't a build error but i want it to be
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Surely the above wrong html will give you warning in VS.
you can ask VS to make those as error.

[have a look to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520853/warning-as-error-how-to-rid-these)

Happy coding

Answer (score 1):

The default for visual studio is to report html validation errors as warnings. You can tell it to report them as errors under Tools -> Options then under Text Editor -> HTML -> Validation and uncheck "as warnings".