# Getting the file size in c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have a file and I want to get the size of the file. I can use only `_wfopen` or `_wfopen_s` for opening the file because my file path type is `std::wstring`.

```
FILE* p_file = NULL;
p_file=_wfopen(tempFileName.c_str(),L"r");
fseek(p_file,0,SEEK_END);
```

but I am getting an error

```
error C2220: warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated
```

Comment: This is a compilation error, you have a warning that has been treated as an error.Try to fix the warning cause or lower your warning level.this has nothing to do directly to the file opening

Comment: How can i fix the warning cause?

Comment: You can get rid of warnings as beeing treated as error in this way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520853/warning-as-error-how-to-rid-these

Comment: Tell us what is the warning.

Comment: Can't you just use `stat`? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/14h5k7ff.aspx

Comment: i can't use stat because i can use only file path as wstring type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get rid of your error message, you need to fix the issue that is generating warning.

If you compile this code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    FILE* p_file = NULL;
    std::wstring tempFileName = L"c:\\test.txt";
    p_file=_wfopen(tempFileName.c_str(),L"r");

    if(!p_file)
    {
        perror("Open failed.");
        return 0;
    }

    fseek(p_file,0,SEEK_END);
    fclose(p_file);

    return 0;
}
```

You will get this warning:

> warning C4996: '_wfopen': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using _wfopen_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.

So, listen what it says, and do the following:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    FILE* p_file = NULL;
    std::wstring tempFileName = L"c:\\test.txt";
    _wfopen_s(&p_file, tempFileName.c_str(),L"r");

    if(!p_file)
    {
        perror("Open failed.");
        return 0;
    }

    fseek(p_file,0,SEEK_END);
    fclose(p_file);

    return 0;
}
```

There is a way to turn off this warning by putting `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` in `Project Properties` -> `C/C++` -> `Preprocessor` -> `Preprocessor Definitions`, but you should always prefer safe alternatives to these functions.

Also, before `fseek` you should check if your p_file pointer is `NULL`.