# VS 2015 marking warning as erros

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

My VS 2015 is treating warnings, such as "Virtual member called in constructor", as error!
Compilation still completes the code is sprinkled with red underlines and the error list is completed polluted...
How can I make these items go back to being treated as warnings?!?

Comment: [Warning as Error - How to rid these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520853/warning-as-error-how-to-rid-these)

Answer (score 3):

You go to your project properties page, and in Build tab, find the "Treat warnings as errors" radio button, then select "None" - or just specific warnings that you want to highlight as errors.

[image]