# [[deprecated]] results in build failure in VS2017 (Error C4996)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, deprecated, cl.exe

```
[[deprecated]]
void foo(){};

int main()
{
    foo();
}
```

The above code yields the following error in VS2017:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: test, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>deprecation.cpp
1>d:\source\deprecation.cpp(6): error C4996: 'foo': was declared deprecated
1>d:\source\deprecation.cpp(2): note: see declaration of 'foo'
1>Done building project "test.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Unfortunately, searching for this error results in a mountain of "how to use [[deprecated]]" and "which functions are deprecated?" style questions.

Every resource I check seems to suggest that use of [[deprecated]] should be as simple as what is written above - the compiler error/warning is expected, but not the build failure. Commenting out the [[deprecated]] line results in successful build.

Project is targeting Windows SDK version 10.0.17763.0.

cl.exe version is 19.16.27027.

Have I missed something obvious in using [[deprecated]], or is VS2017 finding a way to break it?

Comment: Looks like VS is just [treating warnings as errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520853/warning-as-error-how-to-rid-these).

Comment: You are likely building with warnings as errors.

Comment: Well,  the compiler error *is* a build failure.

Comment: Be careful what you ask for. You might get it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You get an error instead warning because "SDL checks" enabled. It looks like in VS17 SDL enabled by default. From [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/sdl-enable-additional-security-checks?view=vs-2017):

> /sdl **enables** these **warnings as errors**:
>
> C4146 / we4146    A unary minus operator was applied to an unsigned type,
>   resulting in an unsigned result.
>
> C4308 / we4308    A negative integral constant converted to unsigned
>   type, resulting in a possibly meaningless result.
>
> C4532 / we4532    Use of continue, break or goto keywords in a __finally
>   / finally block has undefined behavior during abnormal termination.
>
> C4533 / we4533    Code initializing a variable will not be executed.
>
> C4700 / we4700    Use of an uninitialized local variable.
>
> C4703 / we4703    Use of a potentially uninitialized local pointer
>   variable.
>
> C4789 / we4789    Buffer overrun when specific C run - time(CRT)
>   functions are used.
>
> C4995 / we4995    Use of a function marked with pragma deprecated.
>
> **C4996** / we4996    Use of a function marked as deprecated.

To fix go to "Properties" -> "C/C++" -> "SDL checks", set to "No(/sdl-)". After this you will get

```
: warning C4996: 'foo': was declared deprecated
: note: see declaration of 'foo'
```

Comment: Hi Dmytro, thanks for the detailed answer. I went to Project > Properties and set SDL checks to No (also, Treat Warnings As Errors was already on No) and tried to rebuild - was met with the same error.

Comment: @vkn, have you checked that the configuration is active?

Comment: It was not on Active - I changed the configuration to Active, set SDL Checks to No, and the code now compiles correctly. Thank you!