# Can not covert from 'const char*' to 'char*' in VS19, although earlier could

Tags: c++, character-encoding, visual-studio-2019, const-char

I bought a Surface Go 2 today, and installed Visual Studio 2019. I loaded my project, that **successfully compiled** on my previous PC, also in VS19.

The first problem that I noticed is that the VS editor displays Unicode characters (Cyrillic) in my `.cpp` files as hieroglyphs:

```
card->NewTextW(L"Çàãðóçêà", ...
```

Instead of:

```
card->NewTextW(L"Загрузка",
```

Then I tried to compile the project, but got more then a hundred errors, and all of them were about the compiler can't convert from `const wchar/char *` to `wchar/char *`, although, I repeat, that earlier, in another PC, everything compiled successfully. This error appears to almost all types of strings, and for strings with wrong encoding, like mentioned above, and without.

**Specific example of error**

```
card->NewTextW(L"Çàãðóçêà", 3, r.right/2-50, r.bottom / 2 - 350 / 2 - 80 + 350 + 60, 10, 20, RGB(0, 0, 0));
card->NewText("eng-string", 4, r.right/2-50, r.bottom / 2 - 350 / 2 - 80 + 350 + 60, 10, 20, RGB(0, 0, 0));
```

Where `card` is a pointer to an object of interface virtual class `ICard`:

```
class ICard
{
public:
...
virtual void NewTextW(wchar_t *text, int id, int x, int y, int divid, int j, COLORREF col) = 0;
virtual void NewText(char *text, int id, int x, int y, int divid, int j, COLORREF col) = 0;
...
}card*;
```

**Specific example of *no* error**

```
MessageBoxA(NULL, "aga", "uogou", MB_OK);
```

Comment: You seem to be coupling two different problems in this question. One part is the string literals being passed to non-`const` character pointers which is actually illegal in C++, and always has been (if this worked before, it must have had some extension or compatibility enabled in the setup). The other part is the unicode characters, which could be a number of entirely unrelated problems. Please ask only one thing per question as it makes it easier to answer

Comment: @Human-Compiler I understand that it rather different problems, but, perhaps they are related, so I gave more details, including the issue with encoding.

Comment: @Human-Compiler as for always existing illegality and "extension or compatibly" You mentioned, it is a bit surprising for me, because the interface class I mentioned in the post, I wrote about 6 years ago, and since that time have changed Visual Studios a lot of times, and have never faced that issue

Comment: @Human-Compiler, however adding `const` in methods argument list solves my problem.

Comment: @Human-Compiler "*which is actually illegal in C++, and always has been*" - not always, only since C++11. Earlier versions of C++ allowed string literals to be assigned to non-const pointers, for backwards compatibility with C. C++11 onwards forbid it now. In VS2019, you can enable the `/permissive` option, or enable the `/Zc:strictStrings-` option, to re-enable the old behavior

Comment: @RemyLebeau Wait, really? I always thought the string to `char*` was an extension by the compiler for compatibility with C -- but wasn't actually part of the standard.

Comment: @Human-Compiler it was in the C++03 standard, at least: "*§4.2/2 (conv.array/2)
A string literal (2.13.4) that is not a wide string literal can be converted to an rvalue of type “pointer to char”; a wide string literal can be converted to an rvalue of type “pointer to wchar_t”. In either case, the result is a pointer to the first element of the array. This conversion is considered only when there is an explicit appropriate pointer target type, and not when there is a general need to convert from an lvalue to an rvalue. [Note: this conversion is deprecated. See Annex D. ]*"

Comment: @RemyLebeau TIL -- thank you for correcting me on that! That quote also explains why I was sure I had at least seen compiler warnings on this conversion long before C++11, which can be explained by the footnote of "this conversion is deprecated".

Comment: @Human-Compiler C++98 expands on that wording with an example (maybe C++03 did too, I don't know - I don't have the actual standards to look at): "*... For the purpose of ranking in overload resolution (13.3.3.1.1), this conversion is considered an array-to-pointer conversion followed by a qualification conversion (4.4). [Example:"abc" is converted to “pointer to const char” as an array-to-pointer conversion, and then to “pointer to char” as a qualification conversion. ]*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Cannot covert from 'const char*' to 'char*' in VS19, although earlier version could

According to the doc: [/permissive- (Standards conformance)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/permissive-standards-conformance?view=msvc-160)

> By default, the /permissive- option is set in new projects created by
> Visual Studio 2017 version 15.5 and later versions. It's not set by
> default in earlier versions. When the option is set, the compiler
> generates diagnostic errors or warnings when non-standard language
> constructs are detected in your code. These constructs include some
> common bugs in pre-C++11 code.

As far as I'm concerned, this is a good explanation of why this error did not appear in the earlier version.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like the code is working as is for me on godbolt.org

https://godbolt.org/z/nGz3hcG3c

Not needing to change parameters to `const` or anything else...

I do get warnings using gcc but not msvc

This looks like a compiler issue on your end, not with msvc19
I wonder if your VS install has a setting that treats warnings as errors?
Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/66485736/496405 to disable this option.

Comment: The error is warranted since C++11, and msvc [will (correctly) issue it](https://godbolt.org/z/nsWdsqsje) in `/permissive-` conforming mode.