# Make block statements a compile error in C# via Rider or Visual Studio

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings, code-analysis, roslyn-code-analysis

We found the following bug in our code as a result of a git merge.

```
public static void error(ref string test)
{
    var diff = 123 - new Random().Next();
    if (diff == 0)
        test = $"diff == 0";
    {
        return;
    }
    
    //This will never execute
    test = $"diff != 0";
}
```

As you can see the missing braces has caused a block statement with a return in it. Code analysis reports the code as unreachable which would alert most people. A unit test would also pick this up. However the issue is a block statement is rarely ever the programmers intention and during the git merge this error is not immediately obvious (due to no code analysis running in most merge windows).

[image]

Is there anyway to make this (the block statement, not the unreachable code) a compile error/warning via custom analysis rules in  C# via Jetbrains Rider or Visual Studio?

Comment: So do you want to change the compiler warning "Code is unreachable" into a compiler  error?

Comment: Maybe this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520853/warning-as-error-how-to-get-rid-of-these