# ambiguous type for a bitshift; use a type suffix on literal values, like 'L' or 'U', or a cast

Tags: c++, shader, hlsl, direct3d, directx-12

I am using a script provided by microsoft (bitonic_start_sort_cs.hlsl) but it gives me the following error:

ambiguous type for bit shift; use a type suffix on literal values, like 'L' or 'U', or a cast [-Werror,-Wambig-lit-shift] (line 39, line 53)

It is not documented anywhere, as far as I know, and I have no idea how to fix it.

The script:
(The errors can be seen on line 39 and line 53)

```
#include "cs.hlsli"
#include "bitonic_sort_rs.hlsli"
#include "indirect.hlsli"

ConstantBuffer<bitonic_sort_cb> cb                      : register(b0);
StructuredBuffer<uint> counterBuffer                    : register(t0);
RWStructuredBuffer<D3D12_DISPATCH_ARGUMENTS> dispatch   : register(u0);

uint nextPowerOfTwo(uint i)
{
    uint mask = (1 << firstbithigh(i)) - 1;  // ERROR 1 HERE
    return (i + mask) & ~mask;
}

[numthreads(22, 1, 1)]
[RootSignature(BITONIC_SORT_RS)]
void main(cs_input IN)
{
    if (IN.groupIndex >= cb.maxNumIterations)
    {
        return;
    }

    uint listCount = counterBuffer[cb.counterOffset];
    uint k = 2048 << IN.groupIndex;  // ERROR 2 HERE

    // We need one more iteration every time the number of thread groups doubles.
    if (k > nextPowerOfTwo((listCount + 2047) & ~2047))
    {
        listCount = 0;
    }

    uint offset = IN.groupIndex * (IN.groupIndex + 1) / 2;

    // Generate outer sort dispatch arguments.
    for (uint j = k / 2; j > 1024; j /= 2)
    {
        // All of the groups of size 2j that are full.
        uint completeGroups = (listCount & ~(2 * j - 1)) / 2048;

        // Remaining items must only be sorted if there are more than j of them.
        uint partialGroups = ((uint)max(int(listCount - completeGroups * 2048 - j), 0) + 1023) / 1024;

        D3D12_DISPATCH_ARGUMENTS arguments = { completeGroups + partialGroups, 1, 1 };
        dispatch[offset] = arguments;

        ++offset;
    }

    // The inner sort always sorts all groups (rounded up to multiples of 2048).
    D3D12_DISPATCH_ARGUMENTS arguments = { (listCount + 2047) / 2048, 1, 1 };
    dispatch[offset] = arguments;
}
```

I tried removing the 2 lines that gave me the error but it gave more errors.

I also tried changing the C++ Language Standard in Visual Studio but that didn't fix it (It's set to C++ 17)

I also tried compiling the code both in Visual studio 2022 and Visual Studio 2019, but that didn't change anything either.

And changing the compiling mode (Release, Debug, 32bit, 64bit) did nothing as well.

There's not much I could have done as I never had this error before and I can't find any documentation or forum question that has had it too, so I have no idea how to fix it.

I'm pretty new to shaders and hlsl, so of course I have no idea what the cause and the fix for this is. All I did was use Microsoft's own script they provided in their example.

Comment: When you do a bitshift, the compiler must know the width of the operand. That's why you are supposed to provide its type.

Comment: Did you try putting a `u` on the end of it?

Comment: That removes the 2 errors, but then spreads to other scripts, and to places where "u" doesn't work. By not working I mean that putting "u" at the end of a number works, but in a place such as a for loop, I don't know how to properly place "u" at the end of an "i" variable (from the for loop)

Comment: Did you determine the compile command line arguments, or are they also from the script? You might be able to just disable this warning or downgrade it from an error.

Comment: Do you know how to do that? I didn't determine any arguments, so maybe that's why.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520853/warning-as-error-how-to-get-rid-of-these) might help you with configuring the compiler, it would be better not to disable the warning / error though. Specifying the width of the operand should only be required on literals (plain numbers in your source code) not variables like loop counters as their type and thus width is known. Also, removing arbitrary lines  *never* works.